# Can we form a Python List Comprehension in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I recently learnt that we can include multiple loops in a python list comprehension, just like the sequence of the for loop in traditional manner.
So, a nested for loop instead another for loop can be added as a list comprehension as under:

```
result_list = [sub for part in parts for sub in part if sub > 10]
```

However, I got confused in one scenario where the number of 'sub' is too long, while the condition of if can be completely ignored on the rest if even one sub breaks the rule. So instead of checking all the sub in the part, I break the loop when the condition breaks and move on to next parts.

I am sharing a scenario from the code I am working on.

```
for part in parts:
    for sub in part:
        if sub not in a_list:
            var = False
            break
    if var == True:
        b_list.append(part)
```

The above code works. Just out of curiosity to learn the language, can we do this in list comprehension format?

I am at this, so sorry if I miss something.

Comment: You can im working on it

Comment: `pass` is reserved in python, you shouldn't use it as a variable name

Comment: you dont need to pass and break values in a list comprehension

Comment: @Oso you actually *can't* it would throw a SyntaxError and not even *compile*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i kind of thought that would be the case, but assumed the code example worked :D

Comment: So what is this code supposed to do?  It is not clear. Your inner loop basically checks if all the elements of `sub` are in `a_list`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Making a few assumptions, I *think* you need something like `[part for part in parts if all(sub in a_list for sub in part)]`. Generally, you can't "break" out of a loop in a list comprehension. Fundamentally, list comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations. But you can use `all` in the conditional here in this specific case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list comprehension syntax adds support for optional decision making/conditionals . The most common way to add conditional logic to a list comprehension is to add a conditional to the end of the expression:

**like so:**

```
new_list = [expression for member in iterable (if conditional)]
```

Here, your conditional statement/if statement comes just before the closing bracket or after the loop if there are more than one loop like i your scenario.

Conditionals/decision making are important because they allow list comprehensions to filter out unwanted values, which would normally require a call to `filter():`

**Here is the complete list comprehension that you asked for:**

```
b_list = [part for part in parts if all(sub in a_list for sub in part)]
```

For more information or help on list comprehensionsgo [here](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#:%7E:text=Every%20list%20comprehension%20in%20Python%20includes%20three%20elements%3A,the%20example%20above%2C%20the%20iterable%20is%20range%20%2810%29.)

Comment: This list comprehension is definitely not equivalent

Comment: It is beacuse you only need to check once if it is in a_list and therefore you dont need to check if `pass = false`

Comment: and if it isnt can you please explain why, thank you

Comment: For starters, because you would potentially add `N*N` elements to the final list, where `N` is the length of `parts`, if the condition always passes. The loop above (assuming some corrections, because it *doesn't even compile*) would at most ad `N` elements to the list.

Comment: Now with the edit you've made, it would throw a `NameError`, because you have the incorrect order. It would have to be `for part in parts for sub in part`

Comment: This should probably be something like `[part for part in parts if all(sub in a_list for sub in part)]`, of course, again assuming several things because the OP's code, for example, the boolean flag variable, and where that happens matters, and indeed, couldn't even use `pass` as a variable.

Comment: Thank you @TERMINATOR and @juanpa.arrivallaga .

`b_list = [part for part in parts if all(sub in a_list for sub in part)]` this worked as per my objective.

Does this do the same thing, taking the same time as the nested loops earlier?

Comment: @Meet its a pleasure, I adjusted my answer to work in your case